# windows server 2008 at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.erode_1(Native Method)

Tags: java, windows, opencv, server

ENV:windows server 2008 R2 enterprise,RAM: 32.0GB,x64,java:1.8.0_192,opencv3.4.1(jar and dll)

code:

```
public class Test {

    static {
        String opencvpath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\libs\\x64\\";
        System.load(opencvpath + Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME + ".dll");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread("D:\\test.jpg");
        if (img == null){
            System.out.println("img == null");
        }
        Mat hsvImg = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(img, hsvImg, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        Mat mask = new Mat();
        Core.inRange(hsvImg, new Scalar(0, 0, 130), new Scalar(180, 30, 250), mask);

        if(hsvImg == null){
            System.out.println("himg == null");
        }
        System.out.println("cols = "+hsvImg.cols());
        Imgproc.dilate(hsvImg, hsvImg, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(8, 3)), new Point(), 2);
        System.out.println("rows = "+hsvImg.rows());
        Imgproc.erode(mask, hsvImg, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(3, 3)), new Point(), 2);
        System.out.println("erode success....");
    }
}
```

windows server cmd run result:

```
D:\SmokeDetectionDemo_jar>java -jar Test.jar
cols = 1920
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: unknown exception
        at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.dilate_1(Native Method)
        at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.dilate(Unknown Source)
        at Test.main(Test.java:29)
```

but run in windows10 cmd is ok, why is different from windows server?

Comment: The title suggests it fails in erode method, but your output shows it fails between 'cols=...' and 'rows=...', i.e. in dilate method. Please update your question.

Comment: Wild guess: The OpenCV function called relies on a graphics library that is not available on Windows Server.

Comment: window server has no graphics library? how to solve it, or has another way to run opencv in window server 2008